# XMLHttpRequest Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to fetch some simple text over HTTP from JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $.get("http://mydomain.com/path", function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

The result should be `text/html`, but is basically only a simple key-value string, no HTML tags whatsoever. The page is in my control, but is supplied by a third-party (closed-source) so I can't modify the Java that serves out this page.

How can I get the contents of this page from JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've simply gotta use <s>either PHP/ASP</s> *your serverside language* to retrieve the cross-domain request or use a service such as a cross domain ajax service created by Yahoo!.

It uses JSONP which is allowed to do very strict cross-domain requests, but asking from Yahoo! they will retrieve any page on the internet.

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/

Comment: I think there are more server side languages then PHP & ASP :P

Comment: I just didn't feel like saying PHP/ASP/VB/Python/Perl/Java/Ruby/SMX/Lasso/WebDNA/WebSpeed/Lua/CGI ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 2):

You can't request that page because of [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) unless that page has explicitly allowed you with [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control).

Either proxy it server side, with a service such as YQL, get it as JSONP or get the other service to enable CORS for your domain.