# Less.js does not work with CDNs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cdn, less

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="http://mycdn.s3.amazon.com/css/web/style.less">
<script src="http://mycdn.s3.amazon.com/css/less-1.1.5.min.js"></script>
```

When I put my .less file in my CDN, it says:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://mycdn.s3.amazonaws.com/media/css/bootstrap/lib/bootstrap.less.
>   Origin http://mydomain.com is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Why? How do I fix this? I do NOT want to compile .css files on server side. I want to keep them client side.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8176913/xmlhttprequest-origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: On a note for anyone else ending up here: I've gotten the same error on my web host's web server. It was erroneously sending empty responses because the `.less` file/mime type was unknown. Configuring the web server to properly serve .less files fixed it. (It was not a cross-domain request, all `.js`/`.less` files were served from the same folder.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This rather long article from MDN will help you understand what's going on - https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control

Basically you've run into the cross-domain security model

If you're adamant that you don't want to compile CSS on the server, you could try serving it from your own sub-domain i.e. map a sub-domain to the Amazon CDN but I'm not sure that will fix your problem.

I'd actually question why you don't want to compile the .CSS server-side as this will result in the best performance for your visitors and enables you to easily host the CSS on a CDN.

After the HTML, the CSS is the next most important item to get into the browser so it can start layout and render of a page, by inserting JS into the mix you're slowing this down (particulary as JS can block parallel downloads in some browsers, and will block the UI thread while it executes)

Comment: Another reason to pre-compile the CSS: Users may have disabled JavaScript (http://noscript.net). As a result, the LESS CSS won't be parsed.

Comment: Do you think a sub-domain to the Amazon CDN solve the problem?

Comment: You could try adding the following HTTP header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://mycdn.s3.amazon.com`

Comment: @Rob W; anyone with javascript disabled, should not visit the web these days.

Comment: @MarkKnol JavaScript can selectively be disabled with [NoScript](http://noscript.net/). It's a very popular [Firefox add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/).

Answer (score 4):

Amazon S3 now supports Cross Origin Resource Sharing:
http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/08/amazon-s3-cross-origin-resource-sharing.html

Follow the instructions and add a CORS Configuration option to your bucket should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fix cross domain access then you need to look at things like Cross Origin Resource Sharing (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) but this is only supported by modern browsers, or JSONP but this would not be possible with your CDN I think.

I have to agree with @Andy Davies that why are you not compiling the .less since this would fix the issue? is this due to the file size being delivered or can you not compile .less as you push the files live? In Visual Studio you can use addins like http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/web-workbench which will compile when changes occur.