# less setup is not working

Tags: css, less

I tried to install less, but it's not working.

Firebug report this error :

```
Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)
```

My code :

```
<link type="text/css" href="http://static.mydomain.com/css/colors.less" rel="stylesheet/less" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.mydomain.com/js/less-1.2.2.min.js" ></script>
```

Header of .less file :

```
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Length  889
Content-Type    text/css
Date    Thu, 10 May 2012 16:56:51 GMT
Etag    "5cbb93-379-4bedaed496200"
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Last-Modified   Mon, 30 Apr 2012 00:56:40 GMT
Server  Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/0.9.8r DAV/2 PHP/5.3.6
```

And its content :

```
#overflow {
  .a { color: #111111 - #444444; } // #000000
  .b { color: #eee + #fff; } // #ffffff
  .c { color: #aaa * 3; } // #ffffff
  .d { color: #00ee00 + #009900; } // #00ff00
}
```

Is someone has an idea ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Less.js does not work with CDNs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061242/less-js-does-not-work-with-cdns)

Comment: Kind of. Not the same consequences.

Comment: On a note for anyone else ending up here: I've gotten the same error on my web host's web server. It was erroneously sending empty responses because the `.less` file/mime type was unknown. Configuring the web server to properly serve .less files fixed it. (It was not a cross-domain request, all `.js`/`.less` files were served from the same folder.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found. just had this into your httpd.conf apache file :

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```